# Can we define alias_method of !method_name

Tags: ruby

I got a class with some predicate method (example from classic Animal Kingdom).

```
class Bird < Animal
  include Flying      
  ...
end

module Flying
  ...
  def can_fly?
    true
  end
  ...
end
```

Unfortunately, we call this predicates with something like

```
  method_name = 'can_fly?'
  animal.send "#{method_name}".to_sym
```

which worked perfectly till now.

But...

Now we need to call the `!animal.can_fly?`

[metaprograming]We can define `method_missing` adding `non_` methods in the Flying module, but the problem is that in the future if we add another `method_missing` in other Modules(Swimming, Burrowing, etc) there will be conflicts (the other modules will override the method_missing).

So we embraced the most primitive decision, to add

```
  def cant_fly?
    !can_fly?
  end
```

Is there some alias_method or other mechanic that is able to alias a `non_` method? Like(**the following is not a valid ruby code**)...

```
alias_method :cannot_fly?, :!can_fly
```

Comment: No, you can't do this. Why don't you simply do `!animal.send method_name`?

Comment: Could you show more meta-code, because it is not clear why you do not call `! animal.send "#{method_name}".to_sym` when you need a negation. The problems are probably occurring in how you are representing the need to call the negation of the method, and not in your deeper implementation. Alternatively, just adding `cant_fly?` is short (it's pretty much the same length as your desired alias_method) and standard Ruby

Comment: animal = Pengiun.new;
traits = ['can_swim?', 'cannot_fly?'];
animal_has_all_traits = traits.all? { |trait| animal.send(:trait) }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, overriding `method_missing` in your `Animal` class doesn't seem as very bad idea. You can do this as follows:

```
class Animal
  # ...
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    match = method_name.match(/^cant_(\w*)\?$/)
    if match
      !send("can_#{match[1]}?", *args, &block)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```